# Site pagination issue

Tags: pagination

The site wont go past the first page it redirects back to page 1 this is the code for the template used

```
* Blog Pagination
 */
function ptp_blog_pagination_bar() {
    global $blog_query;

    $total_pages = $blog_query->max_num_pages;

    if ($total_pages > 1){
        $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));

        echo paginate_links(array(
            'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
            'format' => 'page/%#%',
            'current' => $current_page,
            'total' => $total_pages,
        ));
    }
}

/**
 * Pagination
 */

function ptp_numeric_posts_nav() {

    global $ptp_query;

    /** Stop execution if there's only 1 page */
    if( $ptp_query->max_num_pages <= 1 )
        return;

    $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;
    $max   = intval( $ptp_query->max_num_pages );

    /** Add current page to the array */
    if ( $paged >= 1 )
        $links[] = $paged;

    /** Add the pages around the current page to the array */
    if ( $paged >= 3 ) {
        $links[] = $paged - 1;
        $links[] = $paged - 2;
    }

    if ( ( $paged + 2 ) <= $max ) {
        $links[] = $paged + 2;
        $links[] = $paged + 1;
    }

    echo '<div class="num-nav"><ul>' . "\n";

    /** Previous Post Link */
    if ( get_previous_posts_link() )
        printf( '<li>%s</li>' . "\n", get_previous_posts_link() );

    /** Link to first page, plus ellipses if necessary */
    if ( ! in_array( 1, $links ) ) {
        $class = 1 == $paged ? ' class="active"' : '';

        printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 1 ) ), '1' );

        if ( ! in_array( 2, $links ) )
            echo '<li>…</li>';
```